# How to to make element move to another element then when click, return to previous position in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Objective**

- What method to use to make item 3 move to another container.
- Then if click again return the item to previous position
- this function should be apply to all items.

**Jquery**

```
 $('#item3').click(function(){
       // What method to use to make item_1 move to another container.
       // Then if click again return the item to previous position
 });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/2rhqmr6y/)

HTML

```
<div id="start">
<div class="element">one</div>
<div class="element">two</div>
<div class="element">three</div>
</div>

<div id="target"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.element').click(function() {
var cont = $(this).parent().attr('id');
if (cont == 'start') {
    var place = '#target';
} else {
    var place = '#start';
}
$(place).append($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [drag and drop](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) plugin of jquery UI.

if you cont want use this then you can try this code by onClick finction....

.JS

```
function onclickIteam(iteamId){
    var x = if('#iteamId').html();
    if(if('#iteamId').parent().prop("id") == "my_inventory"){
        //$('#iteamId').detach();
        $('#server_inventory').append(x);
    }else{
        //$('#iteamId').detach();
        $('#my_inventory').append(x);
    }
`}`
```